# Running Gatsby in Docker with local volume sharing

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, gatsby

I'm trying to set up a Wordpress + Gatsby Docker configuration. The whole Wordpress and database part is not an issue and is working fine.

But the Gatsby part is more of an issue. The idea is to build an image where the Gatsby CLI is installed and Node modules are installed while the whole app is shared to a local folder. Here is where I'm at with the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:14.11.0-alpine

RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gatsby", "develop"]
```

And here is the output of the image

```
gatsby_1     | ╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
gatsby_1     | ║                                                                        ║
gatsby_1     | ║   Gatsby collects anonymous usage analytics                            ║
gatsby_1     | ║   to help improve Gatsby for all users.                                ║
gatsby_1     | ║                                                                        ║
gatsby_1     | ║   If you'd like to opt-out, you can use `gatsby telemetry --disable`   ║
gatsby_1     | ║   To learn more, checkout https://gatsby.dev/telemetry                 ║
gatsby_1     | ║                                                                        ║
gatsby_1     | ╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
gatsby_1     |
gatsby_1     |  ERROR
gatsby_1     |
gatsby_1     | There was a problem loading the local develop command. Gatsby may not be installed in your site's "node_modules" directory. Perhaps you need to run "npm install"? You might need to delete your "package-lock.json" as well.
gatsby_1     |
wp-gatsby_gatsby_1 exited with code 1
```

But when I check what's in the `node_modules` right before running the dev server, I can see all Gatsby modules. Here is a [repo with the whole project](https://github.com/Axiol/wordpress-gatsby). Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command that fails is `/bin/sh -c autoreconf -fiv`. You can check the base image and see that it missing `autoconf`. You need to install it first with:

```
RUN apk update && apk add autoconf
```

Since you mentioned `node_modules`: make sure that you to have an entry for it in .dockerignore otherwise the command `COPY . .` will overwrite whatever `yarn install` installed in the image already.

Comment: You probably will need more packages like `build-base autoconf automake libtool pkgconfig nasm`. Source: https://medium.com/ultralight-io/getting-gatsby-to-run-on-docker-compose-6bf3b0d97efb

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Problem has now evolved to something more Gatsby centered I think. But thanks for you answer